# Django: Minimum disqus comments integration example in development

Tags: python, django

I want to test disqus comments in development mode. I know that [django-disqus](https://django-disqus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) is the package that helps integrate disqus comments but can't really figure out the way forward.

I have a `Post` model in `models.py` as follows.

```
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField()
```

In my templates I have,

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block  title %}
     Blog | {{post.title}}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <p> <b>{{post.title}}</b> </p>
    <p> {{post.body}}</p>
    <p>Written by: {{ post.author }} on {{ post.publish }}</p>
    <hr>

{% load disqus_tags %}
{% disqus_dev %}
{% disqus_show_comments %}



{% endblock %}

{% block domready %}


{% endblock %}
```

So, my question is:

1. Is it possible to integrate Disqus in development on my local machine?
2. If yes, please provide reference/blog/hints so that I can integrate disqus comments in my blog.

**EDIT**: I have registered [here](https://disqus.com/api/applications/register/) and Since I don't have a website, I put www.example.com in website field. I have also set required values like `DISQUS_API_KEY = 'a_very_long_string'` and 
`DISQUS_WEBSITE_SHORTNAME = 'a_short_string'` in my settings.py. I am getting following error: `We were unable to load Disqus. If you are a moderator please see our troubleshooting guide`

Comment: I would suggest you first step in using a package, reading its documentation
https://django-disqus.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Thank you for replying. I did read them. I don't understand the values to put it in the form here (https://disqus.com/api/applications/register/). It requires a website url which does not exist since I am working on my local machine.

Comment: Once I register with url like 'www.example.com', and complete django-disqus setup providing API_KEY and Shortname in settings.py, I get the following error : `We were unable to load Disqus. If you are a moderator please see our troubleshooting guide`